# Error - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm developing vue.js project and I got an error.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Here is the code.

I passed form data to User class.

**Login.vue**

```
<script>
 export default {
     data(){
         return {
             form :{
                 email:null,
                 password:null
             }
         }
    },
    methods:{
        login(){
            User.login(this.form)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and this is User class

**User.js**

```
class User {
  login(data){
      axios.post('/api/auth/login',data)
          .then(res => this.responseAfterLogin(res))
          .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data))
  }
}
export default User = new User();
```

However, no error occured, when I moved login method to Login.vue and don't use User class.

**Login.vue**

```
 <script>
 export default {
     data(){
         return {
             form :{
                 email:null,
                 password:null
             }
         }
    },
    methods:{
        login(){
            axios.post('/api/auth/login',this.form)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data))
        }
    }
}
 </script>
```

Please explain why and how can I pass data to User class?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is data return from your API, but try to log the res or error only then you can see the data structure.

```
axios.post('/api/auth/login',this.form)
.then(res => console.log(res, 'success'))
.catch(error => console.log(error, 'error'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class User {
    login(data) {
        axios.post('/api/auth/login', data)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.data)
            })

        .catch(function(errors) {
            console.log(errors.response.data);
        })
    }
}
export default User = new User()

login() {
         User.login(this.form)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your api might be returning a null value, (wrong password/username like in my case).

What I did was to validate with a conditional, if so then redirect, and that's all. The code is as follows:

```
console.log(data);
if (data == null) {
  console.log("paila bro");
  window.location.href = '/'
}
```

The part:

```
window.location.href = '/'
```

Could be replaced by a different type of action.